# Typedef cannot be referenced with a enum specifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-errors, compilation

In one of my projects, one of the external modules (SDK) fails to compile with the following error :

`Semantic issue`

`` Typedef `MyEnumType` cannot be referenced with a enum specifier ``

But it works fine with my other projects.

Here`s the header file where the error comes from :

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyEnumType) {
    value1,
    value2,
    value3,
};

@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

- (void)myFunction:(enum MyEnumType)type; // Compilation error shows here

@end
```

Since it works in other projects, I guess something is wrong in my project build settings ?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I removed my previous answer. Something else is at play here. I suspect multiple or incorrect definition for MyEnumType or some #define problem somewhere.

Comment: Are you able to fix it ?

Comment: were you able to fix this, I am having same issue in one of other machine with Xcode 12.4 and Mac 10.15.